# Use LINQ-to-SQL to return an object that has child objects filtered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a MembershipGroups table that is associated with a child Members table.  The Members table has a Status column which can be set to Active or Inactive.

I want to select all MembershipGroups and only their active Members

As an example,

**MembershipGroups**

ID----Title

1-----Group #1

2-----Group #2

**Members**

MembershipGroupID-Name--Status

1-------------------------John----Active

1-------------------------Sally----Inactive

1-------------------------David---Inactive

I'm trying to create a query that looks something like the following (which doesn't currently work):

```
var query = from mg in db.MembershipGroups
where mg.Members.Status = "Active"
select mg
```

The result for this example should return a MembershipGroup of ID#1 with only one child Member entity

How can use LINQ-to-SQL to select a parent object that filters on child objects? If I were using straight T-SQL then this would be a simple join with a where clause but it seems to be much more difficult to do using LINQ-to-SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit - Updated answer to return the MemberShipGroup object

```
var query = (from mg in db.MembershipGroups
            join m in db.Members.Where(mem => mem.Status == "Active")
            on mg.ID equals m.MembershipGroups into members
            select new
            {
               MembershipGroup = mg,
               Members = members
            }).AsEnumerable()
              .Select(m => new MembershipGroup  
                           {
                             ID = m.MembershipGroup.ID,
                             Title = m.MembershipGroup.Title,
                             Members = m.Members 
                           });
```

Comment: What type of object will this return?  I ultimately need a List of MembershipGroup objects.

Comment: @Dave Johansen - Its returning an anonymous type. I updated the answer to return MembershipGroup objects

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ to SQL, you can use the AssociateWith method on the DataLoadOptions to set your child filter at the context level.

```
DataLoadOptions opt = new DataLoadOptions();
opt.AssociateWith<Member>(m => m.Status == "Active");
db.LoadOptions = opt;
```

With this in place, you can simply return your member groups (or filter them for the active ones using `where mg.Any(group => group.Members.Status == "Active")`. Then when you try to drill into the Members of that group, only the Active ones will be returned due to the LoadOptions.

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.associatewith.aspx .
One word of warning, once you set the LoadOptions on a context instance, you can not change it. You may want to use a customized context to use this option.

As an alternative, you could use LINQ to SQL's inheritance model to create an ActiveMember type using the Status column as your discriminator and then create an association between the MemberGroups and ActiveMembers types. This would be the approach you would need to use to model this with the Entity Framework if you though about going that route as well as EF doesn't support the concept of the LoadOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including the child objects you are trying to filter on, inside the query.

E.g.

var query = db.MembershipGroups
  .Include("Members")
  .Where(m => m.Members.Status == "Active");

Comment: I cannot see Include.  Is it Entity Framework specific?  I'm using Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: Yes this is LINQ to Entities, and it works - I use this in many of my queries.

Comment: This doesn't work, you can't filter on the members like that in Linq

Comment: Worked for me. I used it like this  var db = new DBcontext();

            return db.ParentTable.Include("ChildTable").ToList();